# Data Processor missing from Feeds' 'Select a processor' view

Tags: 7, entities, feeds

I installed the Data, Schema, Job Scheduler, and Feeds modules in Drupal 7 and am not seeing the "Data Processor" on the Feeds' 'Select a processor' view when creating a new importer. I even created the Data table, and tried with and without it being an entity (the Data module in D7 allows you to define tables as entities.) All perms are checked for my role.

I'm running Drupal 7.41 and I tried with Feeds 7.x-2.0-beta1 (latest stable) and the latest dev version of Feeds (2016-Jan-06).

I don't see a "FeedsDataProcessor.inc" file in feeds/plugins/ like there was in the Drupal 6 version. Could that be the problem? If so, why would it be missing from the Drupal 7 version?

Thanks!